# Error installing bundle in Mura (Mura newbie)

Tags: sql, mura

Just to preface this, I'm a Mura newbie.

I am attempting to create a new site in Mura 6.2 by importing the 'MuraBootstrap3' bundle - https://github.com/blueriver/MuraBootstrap3Bundle .

Once I create the site and import the bundle, I immediately get the following error message:

[image]

It appears to be an issue with SQL executing the insert command, but I'm not entirely sure why. Am I missing something in the setup? What am I not doing correctly?

Thanks!

Edit: I should mention that The database has already been setup and my default installation is running just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Guust was correct, however the bundle you're looking for is here:
https://github.com/blueriver/MuraBootstrap3Bundle/blob/6f9e86a15fbd10d4b88b77dd2f5be467ce8f3582/MuraBundle_default_2015_03_30_12_29.zip

Answer (score 1):

The bundle you've downloaded is for Mura 7.

I believe the last version of the bundle for Mura 6.x is the following commit:
https://github.com/blueriver/MuraBootstrap3Bundle/commit/c62e8fcfc8ba25fe1ca1ef186af1898e894a3c8e

This is the file I believe you'll need:
https://github.com/blueriver/MuraBootstrap3Bundle/blob/c62e8fcfc8ba25fe1ca1ef186af1898e894a3c8e/MuraBundle_default_2016_05_03_17_01.zip

Comment: Oops, you're right. I blew the site away and downloaded this bundle you linked to, but I'm receiving the same error.

Comment: The you might have to go for an even older version. Or contact Steven to see which version you'll need.

I suggest creating an issue on Github.